# JPA 2.1 : Custom JPQL in CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I'm migrating some code that uses `DetachedCriteria` of **Hibernate** to a new one using standard `CriteriaBuilder` of **JPA 2.1**.

I have the following code :

`criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("sin(?) * sin(x) + cos(?) * cos(y) * cos(x- ?) <= ?", value, types))`;

I want to migrate it using `CriteriaBuilder` but i didn't find a method in the **JPA 2.1** Criteria API to use custom **JPQL**.

Is there any way to do it ?

---

PS: I'm using `Specification` of **Spring data JPA**. So in my code I have access to `CriteriaQuery` and `CriteriaBuilder`.

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Address> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

....
}
```

Comment: Define "custom JPQL". JPQL is well defined by the JPA spec, so if something is JPQL then it is in the spec, by definition. If instead you mean SQL functions then JPQL (and Criteria) has FUNCTION.

Comment: In my criteriaBuilder I want my entity to satisfy the following `sin(?) * sin(x) + cos(?) * cos(y) * cos(x- ?) <= ?` where x and y are two attributs of my entity. Does JPA Criteria API give a equivalent to `Restrictions.sqlRestriction` ?

Comment: It has an equivalent of invoking an SQL function .... as I already said ... "FUNCTION". And that is all you are doing there

Comment: Function is to execute just one database function. I want to execute multiple ones. Is that possible ? Thank you for your patience !

Comment: so chain multiple!